# How can I change font of currently selected text using Adobe Illustrator Extendscript?

Tags: javascript, fonts, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I'd like to change the typeface for the currently selected text elements.

Here is the code I've tried:

```
var sel = app.activeDocument.selection; 
for (i = 0 ; i<sel.length ; i++) 
     { 
          sel[i].textRange.characterAttributes.textFont = textFonts.getByName("Arial");
     }
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
Error 1302: No such element

-> sel[i].textRange.characterAttributes.textFont = textFonts.getByName("Arial");
```

How can I get to the textFont element of the selection? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

OK it turns out if you don't have the exact font name it will throw the error. In this case, the font name is "ArialMT". It works now.

Comment: You should mark the answer as "Correct" so others know this question is answered